# Inconsistent TypeScript Error: Why is col.ref sometimes identified as object while other times it's unsure?

Tags: typescript

I'm getting an inconsistency with TypeScript that I'm unable to figure out.

On line 202 I use `col.ref.id` and get the following error:

> "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'string | Object'.   Property
> 'id' does not exist on type 'string'."

But, this doesn't seem to be an issue when I use `col.ref.id` in lines 194, 196, 199, or 200.

Also note that on line 193 I verify that `col.ref` is not a string.

Anyone has an insight into this inconsistency? I'm pulling hairs

[image]

Here's the code I've been having a hard time with:

```
      {allCols.map((col) => !isString(col.ref) && (
          <Table.Body.Row.Cell key={`opp-${opportunity.id}-col-${col.ref.id}`} className="relative min-w-[15rem]">
            <EditableInput
              value={values.get(opportunity, col.ref.id) /* No problem */} 
              input={(
                <AllInputs
                  value={values.get(opportunity, col.ref.id) /* No problem */} 
                  inputType={values.getType(opportunity, col.ref.id) /* No problem */} 
                  options={values.getOptions(opportunity, col.ref.id) /* No problem */} 
                  onChange={(newVal:any) => values.set(opportunity, col.ref.id, newVal) /* Here, typescript complains that id doesn't exist on col.ref */} 
                  className="bg-transparent border-0 focus:bg-white hover:border"
                />
              )}
              
            />
          </Table.Body.Row.Cell>
        ))}
```

Comment: Can you please put your code as text?

Comment: [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) and make sure it's a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into someone else's IDE.

Comment: I added the pic because I wanted the error highlighting to be visible, but I'll add the code as well. Thanks

Comment: The reason it complains there is that *refs are mutable*. In the render you've already checked if it's a string or not but when the callback fires the value may have changed. Since the compiler cannot guarantee the safety of the property access, it (correctly) complains.